# Simplify Product Import Export in Bulk with Custom Attributes Magento 2.3.5

Tags: import, magento2.3.4, export, import-products

I have requirement to import products in bulk from CSV file which have multiple custom attributes of different type (Multiple Select, Dropdown, Text, etc.). Standard Import/Export option for Magento gets complicated for custom attributes as it groups all custom attribute in one column "additional_attributes". To simplify this I have two requirements.

1. Export and Import product based on Attribute Set. What I am looking for is to export all products within Attribute Set so that each attributes associated with Attribute Set including custom attributes show up as a separate column. For import, I want to upload products which have each custom attribute as separate column.
2. I am looking for some way to get list of values for attributes which are of Multiple Select, Dropdown and Yes/No types so basically, I can verify the values before I upload data for such attributes.

I tried to search for any extension which can help simplify this but couldn't find one which meets the need. Any thoughts or suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can import attribute sets and labels using this extension -

https://www.magebees.com/magento-2-import-export-product-attributes-extension.html

After that, you can import all products with the labels that you imported.

For importing products, while you CAN import all of the attributes in one "additional attributes" column, you can also import the products with each attribute under its own header.

The important thing to remember here is that if the attribute isn't part of the products attribute set, the import will show as successful, but nothing will change on your product.

So if you for example want to import colors, you have to make sure that the attribute set that you're using has color as an option

Comment: Thanks for your response. Magebees extension is more about import/export attributes rather than import/export actual products. I already have custom attributes created so extension offering is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Edited my answer. It doesn't have 100% of what you need, but it'll help with the import